# How do I insert a row after several of the same batch ID, but not after unique ID's?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to insert a new row after several of the same batch ID. For example, I have a vertical list in Excel:
1
2
3
3
4
5
6
6
6
7

How would I insert a new row only after the last (second) 3 and the last (third) 6? (There can be more than two or three of the same number) I have code to add a new row after each unique ID, but that does not fully support my objective. [see below]

```
Public Sub UniqueIDRows()
'Applies new rows under each unique value

Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim xTitleId As String
Dim i As Integer

On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "Row After Batch ID"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = WorkRng.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
    If WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> WorkRng.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
        WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this Sub based on your code.
If you need to ignore empty cells add some check for it.
I don't know what will be the size of selected range so I've made `i` of type Long.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub UniqueIDRows()
'Applies new rows under each unique value

Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim xTitleId As String
Dim i As Long

Dim InsertRng As Range

'On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "Row After Batch ID"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)

'resize Range if you want to insert row after the last id if it meets condition
Set WorkRng = WorkRng.Resize(WorkRng.Rows.Count + 1, WorkRng.Columns.Count)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'check previous cell is the same and the next cell is different
For i = 2 To WorkRng.Rows.Count - 1
    If WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).Value = WorkRng.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value And WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> WorkRng.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value Then
        'rows to insert are stored in range variable
        If InsertRng Is Nothing Then
            Set InsertRng = WorkRng.Cells(i + 1, 1)
        Else
            Set InsertRng = Union(InsertRng, WorkRng.Cells(i + 1, 1))
        End If
    End If
Next

If Not InsertRng Is Nothing Then
    InsertRng.EntireRow.Insert
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: The `WorkRng.Resize` is not necessary.   But nice job!

Comment: @Oleksandr Pavlov Thank you so much. I'm very new to VBA. The vertical list (1,2,3,3,3...etc) is also part of a larger table. (1.) Is there also a way to format the newly created row across the length of the table? Would I need to create a new sub and call that sub? Or is there a way to implement formatting within this code? For context, the formatting would be a highlight and bold. (2.) Furthermore, is there a way to implement formulas under specific column fields for this newly created row? (this may be appropriate for a completely different question) Please take this as two part question.